CouchDB-lucene is not connected with CouchDB
I have installed CouchDB version 3.3.3.. And I have also installed CouchDB-lucene version 2.2.0.. I have also set this option in my local.ini file of CouchDB:
[httpd_global_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://localhost:5984">>}

But when I browse to http://localhost:5984/_fti I receive this error:
// 20240525165749
// http://localhost:5984/_fti

{
  "error": "not_found",
  "reason": "Database does not exist."
}

I have also tried this option in my local.ini file:
[httpd_global_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://127.0.0.1:5985">>}

And also this:
[httpd_global_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://localhost:5985">>}

It does not matter. I always receive the same error when accessing localhost:5984/_fti:
// 20240525165749
// http://localhost:5984/_fti

{
  "error": "not_found",
  "reason": "Database does not exist."
}

What am I doing wrong?

Since CouchDB version 3.3.3. is used in this approach and CouchDB-lucene has not been further developed since 2017, the problem is obviously that interaction between the versions does not work. CouchDB-lucene and current CouchDB versions are no longer compatible. Alternatively, MangoDB (inbuild in CouchDB) should be considered for full-text-search in CouchDB.
